# How to pass argument to target in makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile

I would like to clean my dir by passing the binary to delete. In my directory are those files:

```
foo.c foo.o foo
```

I would like to remove `foo.o` and `foo`. Now in my makefile, I have this:

```
clean:
   rm *.o
   rm [...] #the [...] should be the argument
```

So I would like to run `make clean foo`, and the `foo` here would be the argument passed to the `clean` target. I have read somewhere that the proper way should be to simply make vairable `$(BINARIES)` **inside** the makefile, and use that variable in `rm` command, but then I would have to edit the variable every time I would like to compile another binary. So instead, I want to pass that binary as argument to the `clean` target. How to do that? (And Also, I do *not* want to issue the make like `make ARGS=foo clean`, this is too long, I want *exactly* 3 words. 1) make, 2) target, 3)) argument.

Comment: One rookie mistake: Are those tabs and not spaces?

Answer (score 4):

The synopsis for GNU Make is `make [OPTION]... [TARGET]...`, so I suspect your only options are

1. finding or implementing some other `make` executable which implements the synopsis you want,
2. use the `make ARGS=foo clean` syntax, or
3. use a hack like [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html#Pattern-Rules):

   ```
   clean-%:
       echo $(@:clean-%=%)
   ```

   Call it using `make clean-foo`, and it strips the "clean-" prefix and prints "foo".

Comment: can you please explain your last solution?